# Class user not found - problem with classes path

Tags: php, path

Im merging blog with my website and you can see error. I can figure out what path is to the classess.

Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\tibiaservers_11.10.19\pages\blog\includes\config.php on line 54

here is screenshot with the code how it looks like [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6jYM.jpg)

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','simple-blog');

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



// CONFIG FILE 

$BLOG_NAME = "TibiaServers OTS Blog";



$url = 'http://localhost/simple-blog/';

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//load classes as needed
function __autoload($class) {

   $class = strtolower($class);

   //if call from within assets adjust the path
   $classpath = 'classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
   }  

   //if call from within admin adjust the path
   $classpath = '../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
   }

   //if call from within admin adjust the path
   $classpath = '../../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
   }     

}

$user = new User($db); 

include('functions.php');
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: why not use Composer autoloading? It is somewhat of a standard now, so it'll allow for much easier debugging, code maintenance (by others)? Also, note that  using `__autoload()` is discouraged and deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0.

Comment: You should use an absolute path or an autoloader. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Answer (score 0):

> use spl_autoload visit for exemple : https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload.php